# Does the HTML checkbox input have an available pattern?

Tags: html

My question: Does the checkbox offer a pattern? If so, what is it?

**The following is intended for additional context, as the community is willing to offer peripheral answers as well.**

HTML input elements can accept a pattern, which comes in handy for 'real-time' error reporting. Say an input field has a pattern `[a-z]`, any input with numbers will be marked with the `invalid` pseudo class.

I am unable to have a checkbox respond in the same manner.

I understand that sources (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp, as well as people in the comments) claim the pattern match is run after form submission, this does not seem to be the actual behavior. Here is an example of how the input's `invalid` is applied before the form is submitted: https://jsfiddle.net/kshe57ou/

I'm attempting to alter styles of my form based upon this pseudo class, and was hoping there was a way to style the checkbox as well, whether or not checkbox inputs had a `pattern` attribute.

Comment: how would a checkbox have a pattern? I really have no clue what you are asking. validation happens when you submit? What are you expecting to happen??

Comment: @epascarello seems like 'how it could have a pattern' is a design decision, i.e., I don't know how it could, but certainly some logic could be written to pretend a checkbox did have one - I'm treating the pattern attribute and its handling as a blackbox. I've updated the question with an example, since I know the expected behavior is for the pattern to not run until submission.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like a "check this box if you agree blah blah blah" and catch it before submission? I don't think you can apply it to a checkbox as MDN says _"The pattern attribute is an attribute of the text, tel, email, url, password, and search input types."_

Comment: @j08691 sort of - I'm wanting styles that target input:invalid to be applied before the form is submitted. This seems to occur with my other text-based inputs when their pattern fails

Comment: The pattern checking doesn't appear to apply to checkboxes or radio buttons. You'd need JavaScript to handle it, preventing the submission, doing your checks, and then proceeding as necessary.

Comment: If you just want to style it you can use the [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) selector. Use it with a required class so that you can style it with `input[type="checkbox"].required:not(:checked)`

Comment: Any advice on how to improve this question is greatly appreciated

Comment: I still have no idea what you are expecting to happen. Your fiddle does not even have a checkbox on it.

Comment: @epascarello you're cracking me up over here. My fiddle was intended to showcase that the pattern matching occurs 'in real time', i.e., not just upon submission as you said in your first comment - I prefaced the link with that information. I also made it very clear what my question was, so I'm unsure what you're confusion is. Any other information in the question is just context.

Since you are having trouble with the question, I'll edit it to try and be clearer, but I'm not sure how much more I can call out what the actual question is besides saying 'my question: ...'

Comment: @awsunit The answer is there is no pattern attribute. Now I have no idea what the issue is with a checkbox as you are after. The invalid css is applied along with valid when the required attribute is set on the element. Are you saying you want invalid to run without the required attribute set??

Comment: @epascarello your answer showing how to style unchecked check-boxes and/or their labels before submitting a form was my ultimate goal. I was trying to leave my motives on the sidelines and ask a succinct question, but I can see how my original formatting left the question muddy.

Answer (score 1):

You can still style a checkbox with the :invalid when it is required.

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:required:invalid {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}


input[type="checkbox"]:required:valid {
  outline: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" required />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Typically most people would style the label

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:required:invalid + label {
  color: red;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:required:valid + label {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" required id="terms"/>
  <label for="terms">I accept the terms</label>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `pattern` attribute is unavailable for radio buttons and check boxes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern

It's not enough to read the spec, we must thoroughly read it.